# How to check if user Declines call in Sinch

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api

I'm trying to call using Sinch API. When I call, I need to check if user `Decline` the call. For example: I'm device **A** and calling to Device **B** if device **B** declines my call, I can handle it and report to device **A**.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: App to app or app to Phone? Android or Ios?

Comment: @cjensen, both (App to App and App to phone) in android.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the reason why a call ended in endCause on calldetails https://download.sinch.com/docs/iOS/latest/reference/html/Protocols/SINCallDetails.html#//api/name/endCause

```
SINCallDetails Protocol Reference
```

Conforms to NSObject
Declared in SINCallDetails.h
Overview

The SINCallDetails holds metadata about a call (SINCall).

startedTime required method

establishedTime required method

endedTime required method

endCause required method

Holds the cause of why a call ended, after it has ended. It may be one of the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) SINCallEndCause endCause
Discussion
SINCallEndCauseNone
SINCallEndCauseTimeout
SINCallEndCauseDenied
SINCallEndCauseNoAnswer
SINCallEndCauseError
SINCallEndCauseHungUp
SINCallEndCauseCanceled
SINCallEndCauseOtherDeviceAnswered
If the call has not ended yet, the value is SINCallEndCauseNone.
```

So when you recieve callDidEnd you just look at the details of the call that ended

Comment: There is a list of them, but I don't know which one to use for call reject?CANCELED,
DENIED,
FAILURE, 
HUNG_UP, 
NO_ANSWER, 
NONE,
OTHER_DEVICE_ANSWERED, 
TIMEOUT,
TRANSFERRED . Thanks